# Why ternary expression is executed after falsy value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, boolean-logic

As far as I know expressions are not executed after falsy values in Javascript. For example in the following statement:

```js
const result = undefined && 5;
console.log(result);
```

`result` will be undefined.

However:

```js
const result = false && false ? 'T' : 'F';
console.log(result);
```

`result` will be equal to `F`. Why is the ternary expression still executed?

Comment: astexplorer can help answer questions like this. If you look at how JavaScript parsers parse the provided code, you will see that `&&` has a higher precedence. https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/f9da949cbe3ced8392db1f3aca1d332d/74cb60e597a624bc2d89fe86e700b7079fa279af

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because of [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence): `&&` has higher precedence (6) than `? :` (4), so

```
false && false ? 'T' : 'F'
```

evaluates to

```
(false && false) ? 'T' : 'F'
```

So, the left-hand side evaluates to `false` first (taking the first `false`), and then goes on to the conditional operator.

If you had put parentheses after the `&&`, `result` would be `false`, as you're expecting:

```js
const result = false && (false ? 'T' : 'F');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

const result = false && false ? 'T' : 'F'

As we know ternary expression is a short form of IF else condition,the above statement is like

```
if(false && false){ 
    return 'T'
}else{
    return 'F'
}
```

So result value we getting as "F"